# iOS: Twitter Stream API Returning Null For Expanded_URL even though Path is Correct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, twitter

This is json that's being returned:

```
{
    hashtags =     (
    );
    symbols =     (
    );
    urls =     (
                {
            "display_url" = "oust.com";
            "expanded_url" = "http://oust.com";
            indices =             (
                11,
                33
            );
            url = "http://t.co/NY8wYCI9Bc";
        }
    );
    "user_mentions" =     (
    );
}
```

I tried the following: `[JSON valueForKey:@"urls[0]/url"];` but I keep getting `(null)`. Any suggestions? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

That's not how valueForKey works. You're confusing it with literal accessors.

In your case, you'd need:

```
json[@"urls"][0][@"url"]
```

Assuming `json` is the root dictionary of your JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the url parameter from the json string returned by Twitter as follows:

```
NSString *url = [JSON[@"entities"][@"url"][@"urls"] valueForKey:@"url"];
```